# Validation on DropDownListFor not working with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have a drop down list as follows

```
<div class="editor-label">
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardDetail.SelectedCardSchemeId,
  Model.CardDetail.CardSchemes, "Select")%> 
</div>
```

and in my model I am using DataAnnotations

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* Required SelectedCardSchemeId Message")]
public int SelectedCardSchemeId { get; set; }
```

How can I get the message to appear in the view? 
In debug I can see the ModelState error is populated, but the message is not displayed on the view.
I do not have issues with displaying error message for other controls (TextBoxFor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put a validation message placeholder?

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardDetail.SelectedCardSchemeId) %>
```

or:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, forget this. Oops!